# How to remote debug in intellij 12.1.4?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

[image]
[image]

How do I remote debug a java application using IntelliJ 
12.1.14 ? 
There is no Remote option in the Run/Debug Configurations in IntelliJ 12.1.4 like IntelliJ 9.0.

Answer (score 4):

```
run -> edit configurations -> defaults -> remote
```

choose host and port

Comment: It doesn't have the remote option in the Run/Debug configurations.

Comment: @MindBrain i have remote in both community and ultimate version (12.1.4). maybe try to re-install it.

Comment: Hi @Foo Bar User  Yes updating or re-installing will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Remote debugging option disappeared and previously configured remote debug configs were showing as unknown.
File --> Invalidate Caches ... did the trick. Now remote option and remote configs are back, after restart. (I am on ver:12.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Updating IntelliJ version is a workaround to get back the Remote option in the Run/Debug Configurations.