# Play Framework with IntelliJ Community Edition 14

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have not managed to compile/debug etc. the current Play Framework (2.3.7) with the **Community Edition** 14 of IntelliJ. Neither by importing the project, nor by using gen-idea .

Is there any way to get it run or is there just no way to use it ?
Paying > 400 bucks for just this feature is simply too much.

Thanks.

Comment: Single seat license costs around 170 bucks and is well worth the money, for all of your development work.

Comment: agree with Marius, 170 bux is definitelly good price for Ultimate, keep in mind that's not only about 'compiling Play', finally it's free for 30 days, so you can compare easily what benefits it gives to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I compile and run through console: `activator -> compile/run`, but you can compile in Intellij too by running `Build -> Make Project`, but I never tried running Play in Intellij though.

And for debugging, I run command `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` as said in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE). Then I set up [remote debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128264/how-to-remote-debug-in-intellij-12-1-4) in Intellij.