# Play Framework Intellij community edition debug mode Java

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm not able to run play project in debug mode in intellij IDE community edition. I've followed the instructions [Play Framework setting up IDE](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE) page, and did not manage to catch any breakpoint from the IDE, I've also tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390178/how-to-make-the-debugging-in-playframework-in-intellij-idea), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723964/play-framework-with-intellij-community-edition-14) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218341/how-to-run-play-framework-2-x-in-debug-mode-in-intellij-idea), and still nothing worked.
Running `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` from the console started the project, then running a remote debugging session on port 9999 from intellij also seemed to work, but breakpoints were not stopping the session at all.

I'm using Play Framework 2.4 and Intellij community edition 15.

Comment: As far as I know, Play support is not available in community edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/#chooseYourEdition

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html

Comment: Play 2.0 plugin for intellij is available only for the ultimate edition, but the scala plugin is available for the community edition and as I understood should enable debugging of an application. The Jet Brains page informs about run / debug configuration which indeed should help, but unfortunately it does not provide any new information since I've tried the process described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723964/play-framework-with-intellij-community-edition-14).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

The reason breakpoints were not stopping on the IDE was because I a fork command at the end of my build.sbt file:

```
fork in run := true
```

As I deleted this line, everything worked as I expected.

No reason the community edition of intellij won't be able to debug a simple play application. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723964/play-framework-with-intellij-community-edition-14) was very helpful for everyone who gets lots in his way to setting up a simple environment to develop and debug Play Framework application.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Play Gramework (and for other famous frameworks) is available for **Ultimate** version of IntelliJ Idea and that's obvious.

Guys from JetBrains does great job and they just need some kind of gratification for it!

Comment: This does not answer my question nor help me in any way as my main problem is the fact that I cannot catch my breakpoints on Remote Run Configuration, which is a fully supported feature on the community edition. Guys from JetBrains indeed do a great job we can agree on that.

Comment: It helps you at least at one point: you can skip wasting your time for searching for "full stack" at community edition - you won't find it.

Answer (score 1):

PlayFramework Support is only available on Ultimate version and not the community version.[Intellij Ultimate vs Community](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Ultimate+Edition+vs.+Community+Edition)

Answer (score 1):

In intellij community:

- Create new Run/debug Configuration
- Select JAR Application

  ```
  Path to jar : /Users...../sbt-launch.jar
  VM options: -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
  -debug 
  -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
  Program arguments : run
  ```

Don't forget in build.sbt

```
fork in run := true
```

After you launch directly on Debug Button.
Enjoy.